# openGLES and XML code

Tags: android, xml, opengl-es

I am trying to learn program openGLES. I find openGLES tutorial and now I have problem with XML code.

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
>     - Element type "RelativeLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" 
>      or "/>".

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/glSurface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, "Element type "RelativeLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".", so it should start more like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView...
```

Comment: This RelativeLayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style)